# Spring Security: How to Return 503 Service Unavailable?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a RESTful web service that authenticates using Spring Security.  I have registered a custom [`AuthenticationProvider`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationProvider.java) with my application that delegates its `authenticate()` business logic to a remote service, which could be unavailable.  When the remote service is unavailable, I want the call to be able to* return a `503 Service Unavailable`.

Spring Security handles `403 Forbidden` as-expected, but I want to add the `503` logic some place.  The [`AuthenticationProvider`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationProvider.java) interface can throw the runtime `AuthenticationException`, but it and its descendants get handled by [`ProviderManager`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/ProviderManager.java#L191).

Here is my WebSecurityConfigurer:

```
// how do I hook this into 'http'???
@Autowired
private MyAuthenticationFailureHandler myAuthenticationFailureHandler;

protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http
    .authenticationProvider(myAuthenticationProvider)
    .httpBasic()
    .and()
    .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(myAuthenticationEntryPoint)
        .accessDeniedHandler(myAccessDeniedHandler)
    .and()
    .sessionManagement()
    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
    ...
```

How do I configure `HttpSecurity` to return the desired `503`, given I have a custom `AuthenticationProvider`?

*- admittedly, this is a corner case.

Comment: You can create a ControllerAdvice

Comment: `@ControllerAdvice` applies only to Spring MVC.  The Spring Security authentication layer happens prior to any ControllerAdvice.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Register an **AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter** for your web service authentication and attempt authetication from there. You can configure the failure handler in the same filter class.</s>

```
public class AjaxLoginProcessingFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AjaxLoginProcessingFilter.class);

private final AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler;
private final AuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler;

private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

public AjaxLoginProcessingFilter(String defaultProcessUrl, AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler, 
        AuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler, ObjectMapper mapper) {
    super(defaultProcessUrl);
    this.successHandler = successHandler;
    this.failureHandler = failureHandler;
    this.objectMapper = mapper;
}

@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
    if (!HttpMethod.POST.name().equals(request.getMethod()) || !WebUtil.isAjax(request)) {
        if(logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Authentication method not supported. Request method: " + request.getMethod());
        }
        throw new AuthMethodNotSupportedException("Authentication method not supported");
    }

    LoginRequest loginRequest = objectMapper.readValue(request.getReader(), LoginRequest.class);

    if (StringUtils.isBlank(loginRequest.getUsername()) || StringUtils.isBlank(loginRequest.getPassword())) {
        throw new AuthenticationServiceException("Username or Password not provided");
    }

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(), loginRequest.getPassword());

    return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(token);
}

@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain,
        Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
    successHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authResult);
}

@Override
protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        AuthenticationException failed) throws IOException, ServletException {
    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
    failureHandler.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, failed);
}
```

}

**LoginRequest.java**

```
public class LoginRequest {
private String username;
private String password;

@JsonCreator
public LoginRequest(@JsonProperty("username") String username, @JsonProperty("password") String password) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
```

}

Fail the authentication in your authentication provider and implement AuthenticationFailureHandler and then change the response status.

```
@Override
public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        AuthenticationException e) throws IOException, ServletException {

    response.setStatus(HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE.value());

 }
```

You can specify when you want to throw which status in the failure handler.

Comment: Where does `AuthenticationFailureHandler` get registered with `HttpSecurity`?

Comment: It depends which login mechanism you are using. For form login you can configure it as _http.formLogin().failureHandler(<You handler ref>)_

Comment: I added the non-`formLogin` constraint.  That seems to be the _only_ accessor; everything else uses the default `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler`.

Comment: Configuration of failure handler for non form-login is a bit tricky. In my project I have extended **AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter** for AJAX authentication and in _unsuccessfulAuthentication_ method I called my failure handler manually.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it by using 2 custom components:

- `MyUnavailableException` (extends `AuthenticationException`)
- `Custom503AuthenticationEntryPoint`

```
public class Custom503AuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
      AuthenticationException ex) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (ex instanceof MyUnavailableException) {
            response.sendError(HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE.value(), HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE.getReasonPhrase());
        }
...
```